# How to use a table field in custom plugin's settings (Craft 3)

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, table-field

I need a table field in my plugin's settings, but when I make 2 rows and save the settings, only the first row is shown when I go back to the settings page.  When I dump the values, my second setting is still in there. Here's my code:

```
{% import '_includes/forms' as forms %}

{% set name, rows = 'myCustomSettingsTableField', [] %}

{% if attribute(settings, name) != null %}
   {% for value in attribute(settings, name)[0] %}
      {% set rows = rows|merge([value]) %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{{ forms.editableTableField({
   label:  'My Settings Table Field',
   id:     name,
   name:   name,
   cols:   [
              {heading: 'Column 1', handle: 'column1', type: 'text'}
              {heading: 'Column 2', handle: 'column2', type: 'text'},
           ],
   rows:   [rows],
}) }}
```

Dumping `settings.myCustomSettingsTableField` gets me this even though I can only visually see the the first row in the table when I re-enter the settings page.

```
array(2) {
   [0]=>
   array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "Row 1, column 1"
      [1]=>
      string(15) "Row 1, column 2"
   }
   [1]=>
   array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "Row 2, column 1"
      [1]=>
      string(15) "Row 2, column 2"
   }
}
```

How do I configure my Twig code so that it saves and displays correctly?